# Are these vectors linearly independent in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are vectors $\{(1,1), (2,2)\}$ linearly independent in $\mathbb R^2$?

I think they’re not cause we can write the second one as $2(1,1)$.

Is that called linear combination?

Comment: yes you're right.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask, "Is that called linear combination?"?

Comment: Yes, $(2,2)$ is a linear combination of $(1,1)$ since as you noted $(2,2)=2(1,1)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone ♥️

Comment: $2(1,1)+(-1)(2,2)=(0,0)$

Comment: @user Presumably because they're a student.....

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes of course! My concern was about the nature of the doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{(1, 1), (2, 2) \} \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ is not linearly independent.  (You want to talk about sets, rather than vectors, being linearly independent.)

The formal way to show this is to find an equation of the form $a(1, 1)+ b(2, 2)= (0, 0)$ with at least one of $a, b$ nonzero.  As you have observed, because $2(1, 1)=(2, 2)$, it's easy to see that such an equation is $2(1, 1) + (-1) (2, 2)=(0, 0)$; in other words, $a=2, b=-1$.

I'm belaboring the obvious here to make it as clear as I can exactly how to connect the formal definitions to your intuition.

To complete the discussion, let's see how one would use the definition to *prove* that the similar (but different) set $\{(1, 2), (2, 1) \} \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ *is* linearly independent.

Assume $a(1, 2) + b(2, 1)=(0, 0)$.  We know that $a=b=0$ will always be a solution no matter what vectors we use in place of $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$.  Let's see whether, for this choice of two vectors, there are any other solutions for $a, b$.

There are not.  We have $a+2b=0, 2a+b=0$.  The first equation tells us that $a=-2b$.  Substituting that into the second equation, now we have $-4b+b=3b=0$, so $b=0$.  Again using that $a=-2b$, we have also that $a=0$.

In other words, the only way to solve the equation $a(1, 2) + b(2, 1)=(0, 0)$ is for $a=b=0$.  (Note that setting all coefficients equal to $0$ will *always* result in the zero vector.  The key is to determine whether that's the *only* way to achieve that result.)  The fact that $a=b=0$ is the only solution is the very definition of linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Shore's answer above is good, but I'd like to add the geometric intuition. You can visualize these vectors on the plane, where $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ looks like an arrow from the origin to the point (1,1) and $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ looks like an arrow from the origin to the point (2,2). These vectors point in exactly the same direction, so by taking "linear combinations" of them you can only get another vector in the same direction.

On the other hand, if you look at the (linearly independent) vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ on the plane, you can see that they point in different directions. So by taking linear combinations of these, you can get a vector pointing a different way from any of the original vectors.

This gets a little more complicated when you look at sets of more than two vectors. If you have a set of two vectors that are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then you can make any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (we say they *span* the plane).

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, any two (independent) vectors will span a plane. If you add a third vector to that set and you can still only make vectors on that same plane, then the set as a whole is linearly dependent. If you add a third vector and now you can make new vectors in *all* of $\mathbb{R}^3$, outside of the original plane, then the new set of vectors is linearly independent. You can intuitively think of a set of vectors that is linearly dependent as being "redundant", or that some of the vectors are not adding new information.